# Pluralization issue on new question statistics underneath title, with views

Tags: bug, status-completed, plurals, question-statistics, regression

It looks like the new question statistics underneath the question title introduced a pluralization issue with views:

> [image: Viewed 1 times]

To be clear here, this was *not* an issue with the old sidebar-based question statistics; that used to properly say "viewed 1 time".

Comment: that is a rather unexpected regression.

Comment: @rene Judging by the other changes to it, rounded view counts, they've probably just rewritten the code for it.

Comment: @TheLethalCoder new is better ....

Comment: Isn't there a unit test or integration test to catch these kind of errors? It has been more than 10 years now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is fixed. I'm not 100% sure off the top of my head if a build is required for the change to apply, but let's go with yes.

Comment: Re-regression report: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/333674/pluralization-issue-returns-on-new-question-statistics-underneath-title-with-vi

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog I’m not aware of anything changing there again, but I’ll take a look. Thanks for the ping.