# Pluralization issue returns on new question statistics underneath title, with views

Tags: bug, status-completed, plurals, regression, question-statistics

It looks like the new question statistics underneath the question title has [once again](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/331359/pluralization-issue-on-new-question-statistics-underneath-title-with-views) introduced a pluralization issue with views:

> [image: "Viewed 1 times"]

To be clear here once again, this was *not* an issue with the old sidebar-based question statistics, neither was it an issue with the new question statistics for most of the time after the previous bug was fixed.