# First view when posting a question

Tags: discussion, questions, asking-questions, views

I noticed that when I post a question, there's always at least one view

```
Asked today   Viewed 1 times
```

Is the 1st view always the OP?

Comment: Do we have a regression on https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20683/viewed-1-times ? If so, Stack Exchange should stop everything they’re doing and fix this!

Comment: Didn't you, in fact, view it?

Comment: @AndrewGrimm Yes, there was [a regression](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/331359/pluralization-issue-on-new-question-statistics-underneath-title-with-views) when the new question statistics were introduced, then [a re-regression](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/333674/pluralization-issue-returns-on-new-question-statistics-underneath-title-with-vi) you're seeing today.